# How to get a image of a panel with a combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, image-capture

I need to capture an image of panel.

The problem I am running into is that if the Panel contains a TCombobox the Text does not appear.

```
procedure AssignPanelImageToPicture(Panel : TPanel;Image : TImage);
var
 B : TBitmap;
begin
 B := TBitmap.Create;
 try
   B.Width := Panel.Width;
   B.Height := Panel.Height;
   B.Canvas.Lock;
   Panel.PaintTo(B.Canvas.Handle,0,0);
   B.Canvas.Unlock;
   Image1.Picture.Assign(B);
  finally
    B.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using this code, I drop a panel with a TCombobox on it.  Then Enter a value into the Text Property.   I also drop a TImage Next two it.   Then I add a button to call the above
code.

Here is the result:

[image: Imaging of Panel Painting Problem]

Is there a better way to capture a true image of the panel.

Comment: ComboBoxes are painted by Windows, and thus your redirection technique (Panel.PaintTo, which tells controls to paint themselves to another location) won't work. You could grab the entire FORM as a Bitmap, but I don't know a workable technique for a single panel. Maybe this helps: http://www.bitwisemag.com/copy/delphi/delphi1.html

Comment: TForm.GetFormImage runs into the same problem, it nearly the same code.  It does work if I capture the entire screen and then copy out the desired rect but that seems like way too much overhead.   The screen capture code is found here: http://code.google.com/p/robstechcorner/source/browse/trunk/Delphi/utils/SCapture.pas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about using the [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370) functions?

```
procedure AssignPanelImageToPicture(Panel : TPanel;Image : TImage);
var
 B : TBitmap;
 SrcDC: HDC;
begin
 B := TBitmap.Create;
 try
   B.Width := Panel.Width;
   B.Height := Panel.Height;
   SrcDC := GetDC(Panel.Handle);
   try
     BitBlt(B.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Panel.ClientWidth, Panel.ClientHeight, SrcDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
   finally
      ReleaseDC(Panel.Handle, SrcDC);
   end;
   Image.Picture.Assign(B);
 finally
    B.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your function works, having problems getting it to work in my context but I have a direction, thank you.